# How to remove character from variable before use?

Tags: regex, perl

`$a[1]` always starts with a `(` and `$a[5]` always ends with a `)`.

Is there a way to get rid of those without adding more lines?

```
while (my $line = <F>) {

    if ($line =~ m/test /) {
    my @a = split / /, $line;
        printf("%s %2s %4s %4s %.5s\n",$a[0], $a[1], $a[2], $a[5], $a[13]);
    } else {
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without adding more "lines"? How can you change the behaviour of your code without changing it?

Comment: It would help us if you would provide some sample data

Comment: Just a suggestion: Sometimes providing a little more "background" on why a particular question is being asked would help people to better understand what you're looking for.  Something like, "I'm trying to publish a document that demonstrates some concise and legible code, and need a suggestion on..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html)

```
printf("%s %2s %4s %4s %.5s\n", $a[0], substr($a[1], 1), $a[2], substr($a[5], 0, -1), $a[13]);
```